# How to save the whole array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm making a simple game in C# where the player fights until they have no more health:

```
public void FightLoop(int currentHealth) {

    bool death = false;

    do{

      hit = false;

      if(currentHealth == 0){
          death = true;
      }


      turn = turn + 1;
      string turnRecord = turn.ToString();

      string firstPlayerChoiceString = GetPlayerInput();
      string secondPlayerChoiceString = GetRandomWeapon ();

      string gameResult = DetermineWinner(firstPlayerChoiceString, secondPlayerChoiceString, currentHealth, turnRecord);

      if(hit == true){
       currentHealth = currentHealth - 1;
      }

      FightRecord();
      AddRecord(firstPlayerChoiceString, secondPlayerChoiceString, gameResult, turnRecord, turn); 
    
    }while (death == false);

    DisplayFightHistory ();

  }
```

At the end of each fight, a summary of the whole thing should be shown (array with turns, attacks and results).

```
public void FightRecord(int recordSize = 100)
    {
        try
        {
            fightRecordSize = recordSize;
            fightRecord = new string[fightRecordSize, 4];
        }
        catch (OverflowException e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("OverflowException during FightRecord initialization: \"{0}\"\nrecordSize given was [{1}]\nSetting recordSize to 10", e.Message, recordSize);
            fightRecordSize = 100;
            fightRecord = new string[fightRecordSize, 4];
        }
        fightRecordCurrentSize = fightRecordCurrentSize++;
    }
    
    
    public void AddRecord(string playerOneChoice, string playerTwoChoice, string gameResult, string turnRecord, int turn)
    {
    
        // Insert the record data
        fightRecord[fightRecordCurrentIndex, 0] = playerOneChoice;
        fightRecord[fightRecordCurrentIndex, 1] = playerTwoChoice;
        fightRecord[fightRecordCurrentIndex, 2] = gameResult;
        fightRecord[fightRecordCurrentIndex, 3] = turnRecord;
    
        // Increment the fight index counter and current history size
        fightRecordCurrentIndex = (fightRecordCurrentIndex + 1) % fightRecordSize;
    
        if (fightRecordCurrentSize < fightRecordSize)
        {
            fightRecordCurrentSize++;
        }
    }
    
    
  public void DisplayFightHistory () {
    
      System.Console.WriteLine ("\nPodsumowanie:");
      for (int i = 0; i < fightRecordCurrentSize; i++){
        System.Console.WriteLine ("Tura #{0}:\t{1}\t-\t{2},\t{3} {4}",
          fightRecord[i,3], fightRecord[i,0], fightRecord[i,1], fightRecord[i,2], i);

      }
    }
```

However, every time I get only the last value, like this:

*Summary:
Turn #:     -   ,

Turn #:     -   ,

Turn #:     -   ,

Turn #:     -   ,

Turn #:     -   ,

Turn #:     -   ,

Turn #8:    Sword   -   Spear,  You lose*

By following the whole process of creating the array, it seems like the values are being put in it correctly at first, but with each new turn, only the last value remains.
Does anyone have any idea why it's happening?

Comment: You don't seem to be using `i` inside your loop. I think you should be using it instead of `displayRecordIndex` to pick what record to display.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < fightRecordCurrentSize; i++) but you dont use i index. By the way, why ending your loop ( while death == false ) by a break operation ( if death == true break ) ? This is redondant.

Comment: I would just make a class for the game records and use a generic list to make the code more readable. e.g.: class GameRecord { public string PlayerOneChoice {get;set;} ... } and var gameRecords = new List<GameRecord >();

Answer (score 0):

Use the loop variable as the index.

Change

```
fightRecord[displayRecordIndex,3], fightRecord[displayRecordIndex,0], fightRecord[displayRecordIndex,1], fightRecord[displayRecordIndex,2], displayRecordIndex);
```

To

```
fightRecord[i,3], fightRecord[i,0], fightRecord[i,1], fightRecord[i,2], i);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got the exact same result.

Comment: Perhaps do some debugging to determine if the problem is not with how you display the results but with how you store them to begin with. Set a break point and inspect the array. What do you see?

Comment: I added DisplayFightHistory() to the while loop in the FightLoop to be able to observe how the array changes with each turn. It seems that the data is stored correctly at first, but each consecutive turn erases it (so only the last row is filled).